# Is there any difference between 'plaid' and 'tartan'?

Tags: american-english

It seems to me that some Americans will say *plaid* where we will use *tartan*.

Whilst *tartan* refers to woollen cloth woven in one of several patterns of coloured checks and intersecting lines; *plaid* can refer to the same thing but, usually in the UK, it refers to a specific long piece of *tartan* worn over the shoulder as part of Highland dress.

Am I right in my belief that *plaid* is more often used by Americans to refer generally to the cloth? Are the two words used interchangeably? It would naturally be nice to receive a Scottish opinion on this.

Comment: I use plaid to refer to the multi-colored cross-striped pattern. I use tartan to refer to a plaid that is associated with a clan.

Comment: That tends to confirm my impression that *plaid* is more frequently used in America.

Comment: I am one in 300 million :) in may ways.

Comment: Yes. Canada too. I have several plaid shirts (none of them wool), some of which I wear when chopping wood and some of which I wear to casual work meetings. I drape none of them over my shoulder. We use "tartan" to refer to the particular pattern of a Scottish clan.

Comment: @RustyTuba Which is slightly different to the UK usage, though I'm still awaiting a Scots opinion. 'Tartan' is any cloth of that design. As regards the individual family (clan) tartans, I think a lot needs to be taken with a considerable pinch of salt. But I shouldn't complain it brings plenty of tourist dollars to the UK.

Comment: I notice there has been a down-voter. I wonder if they might be a Campbell who has sussed out that I have MacDonalds in my ancestry? Don't be shy, speak up!

Comment: I'm quite sure *plaid* is more common in America. I use it as ScotM does. Just as I'm sure *chips* is used more in England and *fries* is used more in the US.

Comment: In the US, plaid supposedly refers to cloth that has a criss-cross design (whether for clothes or not). But in my experience it is also used for any such design, whether realized in cloth or on paper or however. You could have plaid wallpaper, or you could paint your face plaid. ;-)

Comment: Well, you're definitely correct on the origin of *plaid* (you could have noted that it could also mean a blanket whether it was patterned or plain, but that's not very relevant). I think a lot of people are sure there's some difference between *plaid* and *tartan* as applied to patterns, but don't really have much of an idea of what it is (because there isn't really one) beyond "would a real Scotsman wear it?" which then falls foul of a literal "no real Scotsman fallacy". Not least some of the lighter tartans (such as my clan's) doesn't match some people's expectations.

Comment: @JonHanna The etymology of *plaid*, according to the OED is uncertain, but it certainly is (or was) Gaelic for *blanket*. Somehow I doubt this is the reason that Americans use *plaid* to include things which are not tartan. I don't know what you think but I have always imagined that specific clan tartans are more about bringing dollars into Princes Street, Edinburgh, than any basis of historical substance.

Comment: @WS2 it has the historical substance of being something that in the 19th century was claimed to have had historical substance then… Knowing it's no older, and indeed never even bothering to wear your tartan, somehow doesn't completely immunise one against feeling miffed if someone says it doesn't "look like a real tartan, just a plaid".

Comment: @JonHanna Very aptly put. I lean toward the 'of-19th-century-creation' idea simply because I could never imagine Scottish hill tribes of earlier centuries having the time & resources of modern Premier League football teams, nor the support of Nike and Adidas to provide them each with their individually woven kilts in their clan colours. Life must have been much more about staying free from starvation.

Comment: I've only heard "tartan" used when the pattern is a reasonable simulation of a Scottish tartan pattern.  (Whether or not the fictitious "real Scotsman" would wear it is a separate issue.)  This generally implies that there is more than two colors in each of the warp and woof.

Comment: Plaid is the long tartan drape hung over the shoulder and commonly worn in pipe bands.
I am Scottish and I find the American use of plaid as grating as snuck. Why can't they speak English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this helps at all. I'm Scottish and live in Scotland, I would only use the word plaid if referring to the length of tartan that a piper wears over his shoulder when in formal dress. Yes, tartan is registered to surnames but we also have tartans named after places.

Comment: Thanks, yours was the Scottish confirmation I had been waiting for since December last year!

Comment: @ws2 Why is this the accepted answer when you asked about American English?

Comment: @wjandrea I note that it is now nearly nine years since I asked the question - when I was very new to the site. I hadn't realised that I had in essence asked two questions - one about the American use and the other about the Scottish interpretation.  It would appear that I gave the award to the Scotsman. I apologise if this has disappointed anyone else - but I shall try not to create similar confusion in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on who you're talking to, and the context.
If you held up a swatch of polka-dot fabric and a swatch of tartan, most people in the US would identify one as polka-dot, and the other as *plaid*.

If you were speaking to someone who had a better than average knowledge of patterns, they could probably (and would probably) identify the different plaids as, say, buffalo, madras, gingham, burberry and tartan.

Most plaid fabric that resembles tartan would probably be called "tartan", whether or not it was associated with a specific clan and regardless of the garment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I understand you correctly you are saying that *plaid* is used as a more general term to include things which are not *tartans*.

Comment: @WS2: I would say so, and I think that is what Oldbag is saying as well.

Comment: @Drew That is interesting because, as I mentioned in my OP, the word *plaid* originally had a very specific meaning as the garment worn across the shoulder in Highland dress.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, I read that. Such patterns are very common in the US, but garments worn across the shoulder in Highland dress are quite uncommon in the US. ;-) That might explain the evolution, in part. Imagine abbreviating "a design similar to that of a Highlands plaid" to "plaid-like design" or "plaid".

Comment: @Drew But the OED does confirm that it can and has referred to the tartan cloth, since the 16th century.

Comment: @WS2: Buncha yankees behind that dictionary, no doubt.

Comment: @Drew Well they have an entry from 1510, which I suppose is after Columbus made his voyage! So you may be right.

Comment: @Drew Are you aware that a man largely responsible for the initial compilation of the OED was an American, who was also a surgeon and madman  Dr W. C Minor did it from inside the confines of Broadmoor, then a criminal 'lunatic asylum'. Today it is a state-of -the art- secure psychiatric hospital for extremely dangerous patients. Try Googling his name.

Comment: @WS2: Good to know, and a good example to the rest of us madmen. Thx.

Answer (score -2):

These are all likely more awesome answers than mine. I've actually wondered what the difference is many times. This has always been my semi~conclusive answer, but only taken from personal observations.
I've noticed that tartans have wider designy lines than plaid. 
Personally, I prefer plaid. Just sayin' is all. 
That's neither here nor there. 
Even in the photo, the tartan example has wider lines between t'other lines.

I hope I've provided some useful insight on the the plaidtacular & tartantastic situation.[image]

Comment: Ahh, thanks. If you included the link it would better support  your answer

Comment: Sorry. I messed up the first time. It's there now, just not above.

Comment: That's the only reference I could find though, since my answer is based only on personal observations. More apologies. =1

Comment: I know, I know. Anecdotal evidence isn't particularly reliable. I keep hitting "enter"! Dammit! ;p